# What is the use of Integral and differential calculus?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Im from computer science background,I need to learn the calculus because its even usable in computer programs.

Can anyone suggest me the use of calculus with real time example so that i can grasp quickly

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.disneyanimation.com/technology/publications)'s a timely example of the use of calculus: The algorithm used by Disney Studios to create the snow in *Frozen.* They use a mixed particle/continuum algorithm to efficiently compute numerical solutions to a system of partial differential equations.

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9H1gRQ6S7gg) is a sample video, and of course you can see the result in theaters.